# Change device profile using phonegap / cordova

Tags: javascript, android, ios, backbone.js, cordova

Iam using PhoneGap/Cordova + Backbone for developing a cross platform mobile application. Using phonegap i can access almost all the functions of the device. Is there somehow possible to access or change the device's profile using PhoneGap or using backbone ? I searched a lot but couldn't find any relevant results..!!

Is there any documentation available on this ?

Any help will be very much appreciated..!!

Comment: What do you mean "device profile?"

Comment: phone mode (profiles : silent etc..)

Answer (score 0):

I didnt get what you means about "device's profile". You talking about accounts?

About Phonegap/Cordova you can do everything that a native app can. But sometimes you need to write a native plugin to interact with device. I already had to do that to do push notifications using a third lib.
You write a native class to do something, register it in plugins, give permissions and then call it with your javascript.

You can find documentation here: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.4.0/guide_hybrid_plugins_index.md.html#Plugin%20Development%20Guide

Answer (score 0):

Add this cordova plugin into your project.

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-device

Put these line of codes into your view page

```
alert(device.cordova);
alert(device.model);
alert(device.name);
alert(device.platform);
alert(device.uuid);
alert(device.version);
```